# How do I determine whether a Linux-based router still has the default password?

Tags: passwords, hash, linux, salt, default-password

My goal is to check if the password used by admin is the default password.

I work on a Linux-based router. I know the password is stored as a hashed value in `/etc/passwd`.

In generic Linux machines, `/etc/passwd` has a field to indicate which hashing algorithm is used (for e.g. `$1` for MD5).

Is there any way to get the salt and hashing algorithm used from the `/etc/passwd` file?

Maybe any tool or command?
John cannot be used.

Comment: Yes it is dupe:http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442422/determine-hash-algorithm

Comment: John The Ripper is a password cracker that understand which hashing algorithm that is used in /etc/passwd and /etc/shadow

Comment: I think this is an X: Y question. Why do you care about the algorithim? If you want to check if the admin has used the default password, login with username Admin, password Default Password.

Comment: @Dogeatcatworld I do not have /etc/shadow, only /etc/passwd, that too is in a different way from usual LINUX machine.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace I need to implement a flag which indicates if default password is used. I cannot log out and check in a program. All that can be done is to read from /etc/passwd and compare the hashed value.

Comment: It might help if you could paste a representative line from `/etc/passwd` into your question.  Obviously, don't choose one where the password is a secret.

Comment: If the "ldd" tool is available, you might get a hint of crypto algorithm based on the libraries used (i.e. by /bin/passwd). Checking PAM configuration might also prove valuable...