# How do I determine the algorithm used on an encrypted string?

Tags: encryption, encoding

I have a Microsoft Access database which contains encrypted data:

[image: Encrypted Text]

When I copy-paste it, it looks like `$  8F)`. How can I determine the used encryption algorithm?

How can I convert this to readable text???

Comment: You aren't going to get any information by looking at a view where unprintable characters are printed as squares. At least extract the binary data. But that probably won't tell you much. You should look at the code instead.

Comment: [link](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/device-control-four-4-ascii-code-20.html) Refer for more details...

Answer (score 0):

The string you've posted is UTF-8, which translates to `24 09 16 38 12 16 46 29` in hexadecimal or `JAkWOBIWRik=` in Base64 encoding.

Now that you know the binary data in Base64, you can refer to [this answer by Thomas Pornin](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/4068/43847) which explains it rather well.

Comment: I really doubt the unknown (squared) characters are ASCII. To me they looks like Unicode characters that the current font is unable to display.

Comment: @Diti Hardik4now pasted it here, which makes it actually UTF-8 -  I changed this in my answer. Indeed the characters represented by squares can't be displayed by whatever formatting the access Database viewer is using. But they contain data nonetheless, which is why it should be converted to another encoding to make it human-readable.

Comment: I have tried it to convert in readable string but not getting success..... Can you tell me how can I convert it???

Comment: @Hardik4now If you're looking to convert it online, you can use http://www.asciitohex.com. To do it programmatically, almost every modern high-level programming language has convert utilities.

Comment: I have tried it but when I am going to enter it as password, It doesn't work... :(