# What kind of encryption is this?

Tags: encryption

I'm trying to discover what type of encryption was used to generate this strings:

```
Qo94v0JpPaL59LS6U3xfEB4nVgc=
+3ZaEliGZ7DWte+LaviHvOlcg9A=
v44x/KnS/JyOVDtbmbkFkJEgkWs=
y75nHoG/yXwutlixBX7/jRXsv+o=
Yf0g60vtxLHQttF9YDNM2uYhoHY=
```

Running Base 64 decoding, the result appears to be meaningless.

Comment: This is [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded data.  You can decode each line separately, and will likely result in straight binary output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoded data.  Essentially it's a way to encode binary data into printable ASCII.  You will often see this when encoding hashes or authentication tokens via HTTP.

There are lots of online Base64 decoders.  [OpinionatedGeek](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Decode/) has an easy one to use.  For your set of data you'll want to decode each line individually.  Here is an example of the binary result from `Qo94v0JpPaL59LS6U3xfEB4nVgc=`

```
00000000   42 8F 78 BF  42 69 3D A2  F9 F4 B4 BA  53 7C 5F 10  B.x.Bi=.....S|_.
00000010   1E 27 56 07                                         .'V.
```

It's a 20 byte value, could be a SHA1 hash.  By this I mean the end result of some password hashing scheme that uses SHA1.  This could be a salted hash, keyed HMAC, or performed multiple iterations over `ALGAR123`.  It's also possible that they performed an MD5 on the password first then performed a SHA1.  Here's a nice answer about [secure password hashing](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846).

Comment: What is 20 bytes long? The binary result has 27.

Comment: The value `Qo94v0JpPaL59LS6U3xfEB4nVgc=` decoded is 20 bytes long.  It is shown in my answer.  Each line decoded will most likely be 20 bytes.

Comment: Running SHA1 on `ALGAR123` should be equals to the last  hash base 64 decoded, right?

Comment: Depends on if its salted, if it's an HMAC, it could be hashed 10000 times with SHA1.  They would all result in a 20 byte hash.