# How do ad networks and analytics providers encrypt/hash their traffic?

Tags: encryption, web-application, cryptography, privacy, google

I am trying to observe what types of information android apps are sending to ad networks that are integrated into apps. I used [Fiddler](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/configurefiddler) to decrypt the https traffic. However, some ad networks seem to include further cryptography or hashing. For example, in a GET request AdMob seems to have an encrypted/hashed value for the parameter blob.

What are they doing? Is there any chance for me to see the value or at least find out what the parameter name means (given that the AdMob SDK is not open source)?

[image]

**Update:** The [linked question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used) is not quite what I am looking for. I am more interested to know what ad networks and analytics provider are doing in general. For example, are they using a public key encryption in their SDK decrypting the information with a private key in their backend? If so, is there a way to decompile the SDK and see which public key scheme they are using? Alternatively, are they simply hashing information?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used)