# How to know type of hash

Tags: network, hash, encoding

I just took over a database and one column store a hash string like this format eNoBOwDE/wEBAC1QAAAW12sBADAtAhUA2TflNGxkaH+7qOPrFGDht/1HZvkCFE6tb6DzVhAPS+L4NW7xNZLgo36ZV54Yrw==

Slash and plus stay at same places in every others hash. Does anyone know what kind of hash is it. And also I saw same kind of format in hopper disassembler license file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used)

Answer (score 3):

This is just 70 bytes encoded in base64. No hash produces 70 bytes, so it is binary formatted data, not the hash of data. Run base64 decode and look for patterns. Or better yet, look at what the code does with those values (create, view, edit, delete).

Comment: I was stupid and thanks alot. This was encoded from GUID to Base64. My boss give me this database and asked me write a program to run with it. I got stuck on this, but thanks.

Comment: A guid is only 16 bytes. In base64, 24 bytes. You have 96 bytes of base64. Four times less efficient. That's impressive.