# How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used? any solution ?

Tags: cryptography

QWZpbiBkZSB2b3VzIGluc2NyaXJlIGF1IFRQIGRlIGxhIGpvdXJuZWUgZHUgMTEvMDMgYSBsJ0lTU0FULCB2b2ljaSBjZSBxdSdpbCBmYXV0IGZhaXJlDQoNCjEtIENvZGV6IHZvdHJlIG5vbS9wcmVub20gZW4gQmFzZTY0Lg0KDQoyLSBFbnZveWV6IHVuIGVtYWlsIGEgbCBhZHJlc3NlIHN1aXZhbnRlIDogaGVsbWkucmFpc0BnbWFpbC5jb20NCg0KVGl0cmUgOiBJbnNjcmlwdGlvbiBhdSBUUCBTZWN1cml0ZQ0KQ29ycHMgOiBub20vcHJlbm9tIGNvZGVzIGVuIEJhc2U2NA0KDQpQUzEgOiBMZSBUUCBzZXJhIGFzc3VyZSBwb3VyIDIwIHBhcnRpY2lwYW50cyB1bmlxdWVtZW50DQoNClBTMiA6IEdhcmRleiBsZSBzZWNyZXQgOikg

Comment: Please have a look at all the similar questions, like [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used). The answer is really trivial if you would care to dig a bit deeper. Hint: it's not encrypted at all but only encoded.

Answer (score 0):

Your text is encoded into Base64, I decoded it and it appears to be in another language. I used: [Link](https://www.base64encode.org) to decode it.

> Afin de vous inscrire au TP de la journee du 11/03 a l'ISSAT, voici ce qu'il faut faire
>
> 1- Codez votre nom/prenom en Base64.
>
> 2- Envoyez un email a l adresse suivante : helmi.rais@gmail.com
>
> Titre : Inscription au TP Securite
> Corps : nom/prenom codes en Base64
>
> PS1 : Le TP sera assure pour 20 participants uniquement
>
> PS2 : Gardez le secret :)