# I was sent this, but don't know the encryption method!

Tags: encryption

So, this guy at my university facebook group sent this:

> 536520766f63ea20657374e1206c656e646f206973736f2c20657520717565726f20636f6e76657273617220636f6d20766f63ea2e20457374616d6f7320636f6e74726174616e646f2c206d65206368616d6520696e626f78206f7520652d6d61696c2070617261206a65666572736f6e616e6a6f73407061636b646f63732e636f6d2e

Saying it was an opportunity... That caught my attention. See, I'm a programmer but I don't know much about encryption. I've googled enough trying to find if it was a know encryption, also tried different decryptors online (some in python too) but had no luck.

Comment: That's not encrypted, it's just hex encoded. Google for a hex decoder and you'll get a message out of it.

Comment: Hint: You got a job offer...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used)

Comment: `Se você está lendo isso, eu quero conversar com você. Estamos contratando, me chame inbox ou e-mail para jefersonanjos@packdocs.com.`

Comment: To expand on this a bit, you can tell that a message is hex encoded by looking at the alphabet used in the encoding. The alphabet used for hexadecimal numbers is 0-9, A-F. This doesn't necessarily mean that a hex-encoded message isn't also encrypted, but usually you'd transmit that in text as a base64-encoded string, and to used hex in transmission of encrypted messages would be pointless / inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

Its not encrypted - its actually hex endoded, if you use a hex decoder you will see the message: http://www.convertstring.com/EncodeDecode/HexDecode

The message is in Spanish but i'll let you decode and read it to find out!