# What type of encoding is this string?

Tags: encryption, hash, encoding

I have an encoded string: `VH+_+smN+IPimspbC+_+ygX73g==`

The original string is: `51756`

So `51756` => `VH+_+smN+IPimspbC+_+ygX73g==`

What is the encoding algorithm type?

How can decode `VH+_+smN+IPimspbC+_+ygX73g==` to original string?

Comment: Have a look at this question: [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used)

Comment: I need just decode it. can you help?

Comment: Did you even look at the question I have linked? It answers your question perfectly.

Comment: @ABP we are not a decoding service

Comment: since it's so much longer than the input, I'd assume its a base64 (websafe flavor) encoding of a hash of the string, maybe sha1, based on length.