# Decrypt a text I don't know how was encrypted

Tags: encryption, decryption

I have these 2 different encrypted texts

```
+j+hnQx9Wl83MWeM92tyZA==
```

and

```
E4NEi092gWbppbpNR0JUAw==
```

They should both be long numbers, like `19732832`, but I don't know how to decrypt them. Does anyone know how to help me? I would be very glad if anyone could tell me either the encryption method or just the decrypted text.

If it can help somehow, this is another example:

```
lJsFziTUF4LtFzww7d2tVw==
```

Comment: not that much, it just says it's impossible, but I'm wondering whether there's a way

Comment: @Tommaso I will illustrate what you are asking. I am imagining a random number, then divide that by 7. I tell you that the remainder is 2. I ask you, what is the original number? You say, "it's impossible, but I'm just wondering if there's a way to know".

Comment: The reason that it's impossible to answer this question is because there are an infinite number of answers.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used/227718#227718.

Comment: No, I don't know the original numbers. By the way I'm sure that if the numbers are encypted using a key it impossible to decipher them. But I was thinking of encryptions like base64,.base16, md5 that don't require keys

Comment: @Tommaso Those are not encryptions, those are encodings. So you actually don't know whether or not it's encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously an unanswerable question. We can imagine an unlimited number of possible ways you could encode long numbers into those strings. Just given the string, there's no way to know.

For an obvious example, imagine if you see "4","3","2". That could obviously encode 432, but it could equally obvious encode 234. There is absolutely no way to know which of those two is correct, if either.

If it helps, it does appear to be nearly certain that each of those strings contains 16 bytes of data encoded in base64. Here's the 16-byte data for the three strings you supplied converted into hexadecimal:

lJsFziTUF4LtFzww7d2tVw== -> 94 9b 05 ce 24 d4 17 82 ed 17 3c 30 ed dd ad 57
E4NEi092gWbppbpNR0JUAw== -> 13 83 44 8b 4f 76 81 66 e9 a5 ba 4d 47 42 54 03
+j+hnQx9Wl83MWeM92tyZA== -> fa 3f a1 9d 0c 7d 5a 5f 37 31 67 8c f7 6b 72 64

Comment: David, your byte order is swapped from mine. Probably a function of the tools used.  echo lJsFziTUF4LtFzww7d2tVw== | base64 -d | hexdump -C
00000000  **94 9b 05 ce 24 d4 17 82  ed 17 3c 30 ed dd ad 57**  |....$.....<0...W|     --- same for the other two.

Comment: @user10216038 Thanks. I flipped them.

Comment: I see! The **-C** dumps it out in **byte** order *0 1 2 3 ...* but not using the **Connical** is a 2 byte string order of *1 0 3 2 ...*.

Comment: I've actually found the decoded text. Would it be possible to find how the text was encoded now?

Comment: @Tommaso It is at least theoretically possible with a few encoded/decoded pairs. But that assumes it's not encrypted.

Comment: I don't know. If I post some 2 pairs of encoded decoded text do you think you would be able to help me?