# I want to decode a string of text, but have no clue what was used to encode it

Tags: cryptography

the text is
AAAAQwAAAG8AAABuAAAAZwAAAHIAAABhAAAAdAAAAHUAAABsAAAAYQAAAHQAAABpAAAAbwAAAG4AAABz

I have no idea how to decode this

Answer (score 2):

That look like base64. If the strings content [A-Z,a-z,0-9,+,/,=] then you can straight apply the following command:

```
echo "your strings" | base64 -d
```

Otherwise visit sites which can do this for you eg: https://www.base64decode.org/

I generally visit two websites to decode/decrypt i.e. https://www.dcode.fr/ and https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/.

If you decrypt your text then it will be decrypted as

**Congratulations**

Comment: BTW, you have not accepted any answer. If you find my answer helpful then you can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the question asked here [Decrypt a text I don't know how was encrypted [duplicate]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/230111/decrypt-a-text-i-dont-know-how-was-encrypted)

I will give you a tip on how I decoded this:

1. Browsed to the [GSuite Toolbox](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/encode_decode/)
2. I entered your text
3. Clicked on the second option for Base64 Decode and was presented with an answer that made sense

Now, go back to the link above and read some of their answers for other suggestions.