# Is it possible to find out the encryption algorithm used from hexadecimal hash?

Tags: encryption, hash

Can we find out the encryption method used if we know what is encrypted inside? Let's assume there are around 7-digits 22 or 26 codes (passwords ie just decimals) encrypted to 832 characters hexadecimal. Especially, If we know some of those passwords.

I tried to divide it into 26 sets of 32 digits. But I'm not sure if it helps.

Here is the Hexadecimal code:

```
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
```

And here are 23 codes:

```
0769283 2230455 7532308 5465524 6499201 5421264 5763231 7538211 7251405 6314008 4415425 7805148 3701268 0176160 4005693 5177500 0717127 2322612 9645196 6790118 8246584 1103767 6897031
```

Please, don't mind my inexperience as I'm just about to start my Uni and I hope I'll get some helpful answers. I took this small project to gain some meaningful experience from my friend who runs a software company. Is it possible to find out the rest of the codes?

Answer (score 1):

What  you present is no *"hexadecimal hash"*. It is no hash at all. It is *encrypted* (which is something completely different than hashed) and then *encoded* into a  hexadecimal string. The *encoding* does not matter for the question at all, i.e. basically you ask if you can **derive the encryption algorithm from having the input and the output**.

The answer is, that there is no definite way to do this. One can make up an endless number of algorithm and algorithm parameters which produce a given output from a given input. If one can assume that common encryption algorithms are used though, one might use known properties of these algorithms like block size to narrow down which algorithms this might be.  See also [How to determine what type of encoding/encryption has been used?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3989/how-to-determine-what-type-of-encoding-encryption-has-been-used).